# why are only underscores used in c to name variables?

Tags: c

why not other special symbols? Is this problem solved in advanced languages? I searched for this topic but didn't got satisfactory answer. Is the value of underscore is special(ASCII)? Hope I will find a good answer. Thanks..

Comment: I tend to use a-z and A-Z also a lot

Comment: [GCC also allows `$` in variable names](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Dollar-Signs.html#Dollar-Signs)

Comment: I guess `_` is not an operator in C so it is allowed to be part of variable name and the rest of the symbols (on top of my head) are operators

Comment: why would you really want to use special characters, they are supposed to be a description of what the variable is. I mostly use underscores as a replacement for a space so if i Had a variable for foo money I would name the variable `foo_money` not `foo_$` since that would confuse other people looking at the code.

Comment: Variable/Functions/Classes naming character restrictions is indeed language-depending (and maybe sometimes even compiler-depending but I'm just thinking out loud on this one). Usually more modern languages are also more flexible. I couldn't answer this questions specifically, but it might be that other special characters already have another meaning (think of `*` in C for example) and might thus be misinterpreted by the compiler or create ambiguities... @jgr208 > Well, why wouldn't you ?  I agree you can do without, but sometimes it can be helpfull.

Comment: One reason is that a lot "special symbols" got recruited for other purposes  like operators. I do not see why this is a problem.  And consider that using a leading underscore for a variable has the possibility of conflicting with internal symbols.

Comment: The only other symbols in ASCII chart which don't have some special meaning in C are '`' and '@'.

Comment: @Bartdude I guess that is subjective, and depends on the programmers style so I guess you can do it but its not my personal preference.

Comment: This problem is solved in whitespace (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_%28programming_language%29).

Comment: ohh thanks for ur responses. I was jst wondering is underscore special bt ya that's right too that too that other operators are used in one or by other meanings..one more thing i wanted to clarify is why not spaces or commas are allowed? Even commas, dot,

Comment: aren't used as operators as so..

Comment: @abhijeetpise , Because of the [Comma Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)

Comment: And dot is an operator for member access

Answer (score 6):

Because that's the way the language is specified: see K&R appendix A section 2.2 (original ed) or 2.3 (2nd ed). The `_` isn't special other than it is allowed to be used by the C specification.

If you look a bit further, you will see that most of the other punctuation characters are used as operators of one kind or another so you don't have much else to use for variable names anyway.

Some of us are old enough to remember the days when (on some compilers) the `$` character was also allowed.

Comment: `$` is still allowed by GCC

Comment: But, I imagine, still isn't universally portable.

Comment: @ or even ' doesn't mean anything I guess..so they are I think characters that would have been a good choice for naming variables

Comment: @abhijeetpise ,`'` is used for a character. E.g:`char ch='A';`

Comment: bt for a moment think of it like..abhi's_name. In this case what would ' mean?

Answer (score 0):

Generally White spaces are not allowed in C
In order to seperate word and word in names programmers use '_' there is no certain specific reason but it is better for readability rather than other special symbols
Try this

aditya*kiran

aditya_kiran

the second one is more readable

Comment: aditya*kiran means "multiply aditya by kiran" `*` is an operator in C. Also white space in C is ignored (by definition).

Comment: ok special characters like '~' @DirkKoopman
and also there is no specific functionality for '_'

Comment: `~` is an operator in C too

Comment: k then may be some other symbol

Comment: @ or even ' doesn't mean anything I guess..so they are I think characters that would have been a good choice for naming variables